# MBP late 2008 HDD and SSD setup

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, ssd, hdd

I just upgraded my old MBP to SSD and put my old HDD in my optical drive space for a duo-HD setup. I am running Yosemite on the SSD.

I wanted to use my HDD as a Window 7 setup. However, when I go into boot camp to do this, my computer shuts down and hangs. Is this because of the boot sequence of optical drive comes first? Or is this due to something else?

Can I not run windows on the old HDD?

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply wanting to dedicate your old HDD to Windows 7 duties you don't need to use Boot Camp to do it. Simply partition and format the HDD as FAT (Windows will insist on it being formatted as NTFS when installing), reboot your Mac while holding alt/option and insert your Windows install media. You will then be able to install Windows without further issues.

Boot Camp is only necessary when dual-booting from a single drive. OS X requires a GPT partition to boot from whereas Windows 7 expects an MBR partition. Boot Camp creates a hybrid partition table that works for both systems, but this process isn't necessary if each system has its own dedicated drive.